# What is the right way to go for making this game?

Tags: java

I want to make a game similar to http://www.i-am-bored.com/bored_link.cfm?link_id=24495, but so far I have been unsuccessful. I think I should use an int[] for the x and y positions of the blocks... But I am not sure how I can easily do this.

Here is my code (I know it's a bit messy). Panel is the JPanel, Block are the blocks moving left and right and DeadBlock are the blocks that are stationary and already placed.

The game is so simple, but I am having a hard time with placing the DeadBlocks.

```
package com.valgriz.game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener {
    private Thread thread;

    private final int ARRAY_NUMS = 999;

    private int sleepTime = 200;
    private int rights = 5;
    private int lefts = 0;
    private int dbCurrent;
    private int drawThisMany;

    private boolean isSpaced;

    private Block block;
    private DeadBlock[] dBlock = new DeadBlock[ARRAY_NUMS];
    private int[] dbX = new int[ARRAY_NUMS];
    private int[] dbY = new int[ARRAY_NUMS];

    public Panel() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        block = new Block();
        drawThisMany = 0;
        drawThisMany += rights;
        for (int i = 0; i < dBlock.length; i++) {
            dBlock[i] = new DeadBlock();
        }

        dbCurrent = 0;

        // Thread
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            update();
            try {
                thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        block.update();
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        for (int i = lefts; i < rights; i++) {
            int bX = block.getX();
            if (bX == getWidth() - block.getDx() * rights) {
                block.setDx(block.getDx() * -1);
            }
            if (bX == 0) {
                block.setDx(block.getDx() * -1);
            }

            g.drawImage(block.getBlock(), i * block.getWidth() + block.getX(),
                    getHeight() - block.getDy() * block.getY(), this);

            dbPaint(g);
        }
        // Toolkit
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();

    }

    ////// This code is useless
    public void dbPaint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < drawThisMany; i++) {
            dbX[i] = block.getX() + i * block.getX();
            dbY[i] = getHeight() - block.getY() * block.getWidth();
            g.drawImage(dBlock[i].getImage(), dbX[i], dbY[i], this);
        }

    }

    public void spaced() {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            spaced();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

---

```
package com.valgriz.game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Block {
    private ImageIcon bii;
    private Image block;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int dX;
    private int dY;
    private int pos;
    private int width;

    public Block() {
        bii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(
                "/raw/images/ss_block.png"));
        block = bii.getImage();

        dX = getBlock().getWidth(null);
        dY = getBlock().getHeight(null);
        width = getBlock().getWidth(null);

        x = 0;
        y = 1;
    }

    public void update() {
        x += dX;
    }

    public Image getBlock() {
        return block;
    }

    public int getDx() {
        return dX;
    }

    public void setDx(int dX) {
        this.dX = dX;
    }

    public int getDy() {
        return dY;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
 }
```

---

```
package com.valgriz.game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class DeadBlock {
    private Block block;

    private ImageIcon bii;
    private Image dBlock;

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public DeadBlock() {
        bii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(
                "/raw/images/ss_block.png"));
        dBlock = bii.getImage();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return dBlock;
    }
}
```

What is the right direction and how can I make this code work?

Comment: Mind being a bit clearer about what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I want it to be so when I press the space bar, DeadBlocks are drawn in the positions where the blocks are... then I want the DeadBlocks to stay there...

Comment: I am now playing this game, interesting xD

Comment: after that happens, I will change the y value of Blocks, so they move up a row...

Comment: Thanks for the really addicting game. Now I can't write an answer since my spacebarisgone. :D

Comment: hey you are not supposed to just put hell of a code and clear nothing.

Comment: what?
I know the code is really messy, I just posted it because I know how much people on stack love to see the code.  I hoped it would better explain what I was trying to do.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific, no one will write a program for you. When designing a project, it helps to separate the "data model" from the "display model". So, first you should figure out what exactly you need (eg. a block object, a row object composed of number of blocks, etc.). After that, try displaying each object on screen. If/when you run into a specific problem, _then_ post on SO.

Comment: so... does anyone have any input for me?
I'm sure I could use a 2D array somehow... but I am new to game programming, this will only be my third game and I need to figure this out or it will bother me :P

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about gamedev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A working example

[image: Give it a try!]

It is not perfect, but it is probably good as a reference:

```
package stackgame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class StackGame extends JApplet {
    private final static int BOX_SIZE = 15;
    private final static int ROWS = 30;
    private final static int COLS = 15;

    private static int currentRow = 1;
    private static int currentCount = 9;
    private static JFrame f = new JFrame();

    private static JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, COLS * BOX_SIZE, (ROWS + 1) * BOX_SIZE);

            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            for (int j = 0 ; j < ROWS ; j++) {
                for (int i = 0 ; i < COLS ; i++) {
                    if (boxes[i][j]) {
                        g.fillRect(
                                (i * BOX_SIZE) + 1,
                                (ROWS * BOX_SIZE) - (j * BOX_SIZE) + 1,
                                BOX_SIZE - 2,
                                BOX_SIZE - 2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private static long sleepTime = 500;

    private static Thread moveBoxesThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime );
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
                moveRow();
                gamePanel.repaint();
            }
        }
    };

    static boolean[][] boxes = new boolean[COLS][ROWS];
    static {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < COLS ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < ROWS ; j++) {
                boxes[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
        moveBoxesThread.setDaemon(true);
    }

    private static boolean movingRight = true;

    private static void startGame() {
        for (int i = 3 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
            boxes[i][0] = true;
        }

        initRow();

        gamePanel.repaint();
        startKeyListenning();
        moveBoxesThread.start();
    }

    private static void initRow() {
        if (currentRow >= ROWS) {
            moveBoxesThread.interrupt();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "You win, StackOverFlow!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for (int i = 0 ; i < currentCount ; i++) {
            boxes[i][currentRow] = true;
        }
    }

    private static void startKeyListenning() {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(
            new KeyEventDispatcher() {

                @Override
                public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (!f.isFocusOwner() || currentRow > ROWS - 1)
                        return false;
                    if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED
                            && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                        checkRowAndProceed();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
        });
    }

    protected static synchronized void checkRowAndProceed() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < COLS ; i++) {
            try {
                if (!boxes[i][currentRow - 1]) {
                    boxes[i][currentRow] = false;
                }
                if (boxes[i][currentRow]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        currentCount = count;
        if (currentCount == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "You loose!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        currentRow++;
        movingRight  = true;
        initRow();
        sleepTime *= 95;
        sleepTime /= 100;
    }

    protected static synchronized void moveRow() {
        if (!movingRight) {
            for (int col = 0 ; col < COLS - 1 ; col++) {
                boxes[col][currentRow] = boxes[col + 1][currentRow];
            }
            boxes[COLS - 1][currentRow] = false;
        }
        else {
            for (int col = COLS - 1 ; col > 0 ; col--) {
                boxes[col][currentRow] = boxes[col - 1][currentRow];
            }
            boxes[0][currentRow] = false;
        }
        if ((movingRight && boxes[COLS - 1][currentRow])
                || (!movingRight && boxes[0][currentRow])) {
            movingRight = !movingRight;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            gamePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(COLS * BOX_SIZE, (ROWS + 1) * BOX_SIZE));
            f.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
            f.pack();
            f.setResizable(false);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);

            startGame();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you using a synchronized method?

Comment: The `synchronized` protects the program from a [Memory consistency error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html), where the `moveBoxesThread` and the `checkRowAndProceed` method (which is running on the ` event Dispatch Thread`) both read and write the `boxes` array at the same time.

Comment: The reason why I wrote this answer in the first place, when others voted down instead, is so you can ask such questions and get answers. Keep ask about anything that's not clear enought.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write simple Java/[Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29)/[AWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) games, I strongly recommend *[Developing Games in Java](http://www.brackeen.com/javagamebook/)*.

This book explains everything: how to write a clean game loop, how to handle all the Swing repaint problems that occur, how to make it fullscreen, integrate sound and much more. I see a lot of strange little things in your code which can be fixed with a little study.

Comment: Thank you, I have actually seen this before, I am really considering getting it for myself.

Comment: I would, it's fun with all the examples and easy to read.

Comment: did you recommend this book to someone else on another SO post?
because a couple days ago... I saw someone recommend this book, I've been looking at it since.

Comment: No I did not this is the first time